# How to add pub dev libraries at time of flutter create?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-pub

I am creating a script to automatically create a flutter project. In this, I want to add few libs in pubspec.yaml file everytime a project is created by this script.

i tried using `flutter pub add http` in the script after flutter create myapp but its not adding any libs in pubspec.yaml

Comment: It would be helpful if the script code is shown.